# During bulk insert date is detected as null

Tags: csv, ms-access

In one of my applications I am importing csv data into mt Access db using the following bulk insert query.

```
INSERT INTO Log_134_temp ([DATE],[TIME],CH0,CH1,CH2,CH3) SELECT [DATE],[TIME],CH0,CH1,CH2,CH3 FROM [Text;FMT=CSVDelimited;HDR=Yes;DATABASE=C:\tmp].[SAMPLE_1.csv]
```

The query gets executed and all the parameters in the query are correct. The issue is with just one of the csv files which gives the following error after the query is executed.

> The field 'Log_134_temp.date' cannot contain a Null value because the
>   Required property for this field is set to True.  Enter a value in
>   this field.

Where as the other csv files get imported without any issue.

The file that is imported successfully and the file with the issue however look identical with their formats. And this has puzzled me over a day now.

The file that gets imported

https://www.dropbox.com/s/amddhzhi6nr24ex/SAMPLE_1_111.csv?dl=0

The file that doesn't get imported

https://www.dropbox.com/s/2rrgdf7oor5ptbf/SAMPLE_1_112.csv?dl=0

Comment: Don't expect people to download files, and indeed not to create a Dropbox account just for this.

Comment: Hi, Gustav, for your information, one doesn't need a dropbox account to download a shared file you may click the link and verify yourself and let me know. The attached files are supporting documents without which suggesting a solution may be impossible/difficult and so its my duty to provide it. If its possible for some one to make suggestions without them they anyway can.

Comment: Well, but we can't do anything else, than you can do yourself: Split the offending file in two and check each. Split the offending half file in two and check each. Split the offending quarter file in two and check each. And so on. Amazingly fast you will have located the offending line(s).

Comment: Sort the file by date to find the empty row(s). Or the ones with illegal data.

Comment: Unlike what we discussed, viilpe actually downloaded the file to test, and that's a great gesture. So guess attachments are not a bad thing to have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bad line in row 135169:

```
                                    2019-02-14,16:57:54,310,837,300,650
```

It contains a lot of **00** symbols.

I found this with help of simple Python cycle:

```py
In [43]: f = read_file(r'...SAMPLE_1_112.csv')
In [44]: li = f.split('\n')
...
In [60]: prev_len = 1
In [61]: for l in li:
    ...:     if not len(l): continue
    ...:     if prev_len != len(l): print(l)
    ...:     prev_len = len(l)
    ...:
DATE,TIME,CH0,CH1,CH2,CH3
2018-10-03,11:45:44,246,621,250,600
                                    2019-02-14,16:57:54,310,837,300,650
2019-02-14,16:59:01,309,859,300,650
```

Comment: Hi viilpe, I just came to update with the same answer as yours.But, I shall accept this as an answer for your time and efforts. Thanks a lot.